# Нужна помощь человека, который хорошо знает python и умеет понятно объяснять

Tags: python, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Я  хотел стать веб-дизайнером, учил html, css (вроде выучил), потом начал учить javascript (почти сразу бросил), потом php. Позже друг написал про Сириус (лагерь для 7-9 классов), а для него надо знать с++ или python, но я даже основ не знал ни одного из этих двух языков, начал учить. За первые несколько дней выучил основы. Некоторые задания на сайте решил сам, некоторые он (друг) объяснил, как решать, но те, в которых надо писать код, я вообще не могу ничего сделать. Я разобрался с циклами, массивами (друг говорит, что можно решить эти задания через них). он пытался мне объяснить что-то, но я чересчур тупой. Я просто тупой до ужаса, я даже такие простые задания типа 
**"Найдите индексы первого вхождения максимального элемента. Выведите два числа: номер строки и номер столбца, в которых стоит наибольший элемент в двумерном массиве. Если таких элементов несколько, то выводится тот, у которого меньше номер строки, а если номера строк равны то тот, у которого меньше номер столбца.**

**Программа получает на вход размеры массива n и m, затем n строк по m чисел в каждой."**
*(задание взято с сайта, на котором я учу python)* 
Решаю по несколько часов просто потому, что думаю, как их решить. Я очень хочу попасть в Сириус, потому что то, чему меня там научат, очень пригодится мне. Я всё ещё хочу быть веб-дизайнером и знаю, что на python'e можно писать сайты, поэтому я должен попасть туда. 
Если Вы хорошо знаете python и готовы объяснить мне то, что мне непонятно, отзовитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: За 300 рублей в час готов объяснять

Comment: Надеюсь, я правильно вас понял, и вы хотели решение задачи : ) Если нет, и вам нужна помощь не только с этой задачей - напишите комментарий к моему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, можете [почитать](https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/dvumernye-massivy-v-python) про двумерные массивы в Python.

```
data= []
n, m = map(int,input().split()) #вводятся сразу 2 числа n и m



for i in range(n-2):  #создаём 2мерный массив    
    data.append([] * m) #добавляем в каждую строку m пустых элементов

for i in range(n):#ввод массива
    data.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

max = data[0][0] #примечание 1
maxline = 0
maxcol = 0

for i in range(n):   #цикл перибирает все значения массива data  
    for y in range(m):        
        if data[i][y] > max: #если встречает значение больше максимума,
            #какой же это максимум если есть элементы больше него?
            max = data[i][y]#макс теперь равен этому элементу
            maxline = i #записыва.тся строки и колонки, где находится максимум
            maxcol = y

print(maxline+1, maxcol+1) #здесь +1,
#т.к. вы написали "Выведите два числа: номер строки и номер столбца"
#А номер строки/столбца на 1 больше индекса элемента в массиве
```

Примечание 1: `max = data[0][0]` для того, чтобы в условии `if data[i][y] > max:` не появлялось ошибок. Например, мы создали переменную max со значением 0, а в массиве отрицательные числа - условие не выполняется, т.к. 0 > отрицательных чисел и результат работы программы неправильный. А если `max = data[0][0]` - в переменную записывается значение, которое точно есть в массиве, и если оно максимальное - ответ всё равно будет правильный.

Пример ввода:

```
2 2 - размер массива
1 2 - элементы массива 1й строки
3 4 - и 2й строки
```

Вывод:
`2 2` - элемент №2 во 2й строке максимален

Вы писали:

> для него надо знать с++ или python

Я так понял, вы выбрали Python, но я всё равно предложу вам вариант на c++, вдруг пригодится

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

int main(){
    int n, m, max, maxline = 0, maxcol = 0; //создаём те же переменные
    cin >> n >> m;
    int** data = new int*[n]; //Примечание 2
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        data[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ //ввод значений
        for (int y = 0; y < m; y++){
            cin >> data[i] [y];
        }
    }
    max = data[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ //поиск максимума и его расположения
        for (int y = 0; y < m; y++){
            if (data[i][y] > max){
                max = data[i][y];
                maxline = i;
                maxcol = y;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << maxline + 1 << " " << maxcol + 1; //вывод

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){ //Очистка памяти (примечание 3)
        delete [] data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
    return 0;
}
```

Некоторые объяснения я опустил, потому что они такие же, как в Python

Примечание 2:

В Python вы можете просто написать data.append([]) и массив увеличится на 1 элемент и поместит в себя элемент. В c++ так нельзя. Можно или использовать более простые, статические массивы и указывать их размер в коде, или, более сложные, динамические массивы, и не ограничивать себя размером, указанным в коде. Для этого создаётся массив указателей, а потом, каждый указатель преобразовывается в массив. Таким образом мы получаем динамический двумерный массив размером n на m.

Примечание 3:

Статические массивы сами освобождают после себя память, когда программа завершается или уходит из их [зоны видимости](https://codelessons.ru/cplusplus/oblast-vidimosti-peremennyx-v-c-lokalnye-i-globalnye-peremennye.html). А динамические массивы так не делают. Они могут всё равно освободить память по завершению программы, а могут не очистить, тогда поможет только перезагрузка пк. Есть теория, что Google Chrome использует так много ОЗУ из за того, что кто-то забыл сделать очистку памяти.

Если используете динамические массивы в c++ - следуйте правилу: "Я тебя создал, я тебя и удалю!" - сказал мой учитель по C++